# Routing traffic through VPN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn, vps

I'm trying to route traffic through a VPN. I want to run OPENVPN on both my home server and my VPS. I want to redirect any traffic sent to one of the IP's on my VPS directly to my home server. I also want all the traffic from my home server to go through the VPS. How would I do this? I run ubuntu 20.04 on both servers. I've seen some posts about this but they don't apply to me. If you find a post that can help me please send it to me.

Comment: As you can see, with a non-specific question you can only get a non-specific answer. Improve your question with more details to get a more detailed answer. Actually this question should be split into multiple questions (asked separately). 1st: about having a VPN working, *after showing you made efforts on this* which you didn't currently , 2nd: about special routing applied to a working VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Routing is actually very simple when you think about it.  I recommend reading about different types of routes: host routes, net routes, and default routes, and the commands used to create them.

A host route defines a route to a particular host.  A net route routes to an entire subnet.  A default route defines the gateway - the route used for outgoing traffic, that is not specified in any other routes.

In your case it sounds like you want one host route to a particular host and a default route that points to the VPS.

When everything is connected via OpenVPN examine the existing routing table and determine what additional routes you need/want.  OpenVPN has a configuration option to add routes automatically when clients connect.

When setting up routing it is very helpful to use the ping command to check of packets are routing correctly.